# Template Prestahop, intalation local windows

Tags: windows-7-x64, prestashop-1.6, easyphp

I installed prestashop locally with EasyPhp.
I installed the release **prestashop_1.6.1.0** and everything works with the default theme "**default-bootstrap**".

I bought a new theme on addons: **MyTheme.zip** and I want to install it locally from the BO but I have a problem. When I downloaded **MyTheme.zip** I get an error that appears a few seconds (page on white background):

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 8547237 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

... Then nothing happens. I return to the backoffice and the theme is not added.

I do not understand .. you have an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: while configuration php : upload max filesize : 50M and MyTheme.zip = 6Mo ..

Comment: Check my answer. You have to update your `post_max_size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8388608 bytes is 8M - the default limit in PHP.
You have to update your `post_max_size` in php.ini to a larger value.

`post_max_size` sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: it's exactly that ! Thank you

Comment: I'm glad to hear it ;).